# Lenovo thinkpad W540 and Ubuntu 15:10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lenovo

I am a new user of Linux OS

I have this laptop w540 with these configurations

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

Physical Memory           DDR3, 32.000 GB

Logical Sector Size       Samsung ssd 512GB

video card devices

Quadro K2100M Memory Size        2.00 GBs

Intel(R) HD Graphics Memory Size  1.27 GBs

Bios version 2.24

and I installed windows 7  64 bit on it

with 3 partition (NTFS) one for the windows, one for my files and the 3rd 
conserved for the Linux Ubuntu.

I download the version (ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64b).

I used (Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1) to burn on USB flash drive.

It booted from USB normally but it freezing on starting image.

I tried both live ubuntu and install ubuntu.

is there anything I must do before this step ?

and does the ubuntu work well with my dvice?

if an old version of this OS is recurred please tell me.

thank you
with my Best

Comment: See if creating the USB media works better using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). UUI doesn't seem to work well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

not sure on ubuntu, but there is an issue with bios 2.24.  You need to unplug the laptop from the dock, remove the battery, wait about 30 seconds, reinstall battery, and boot up.  Make sure nothing is in the usb slots on the laptop when you do this.  Lenovo is working on it, for some time now.  They no longer offer that bios on their website.